# If $f(xy) = e^{xy – x – y} (e^y f(x) + e^x f(y)) , x , y \in \mathbb R^+$ and $f ’ (1) = e$ , then find $f(x)$.

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

The following question is taken from the practice set of JEE exam.

> Let $f : \mathbb R^+ → \mathbb R$ satisfies the equation $f(xy) = e^{xy – x – y} (e^y f(x) + e^x f(y)) , x , y \in \mathbb R^+$. If $f ’ (1) = e$ , then find $f(x)$.

My attempt:

$$f(xy)=e^{xy}\left(\dfrac{f(x)}{e^x}+\dfrac{f(y)}{e^y}\right)$$

Putting $x=1=y$, I get $$f(1)=2f(1)\implies f(1)=0$$

Putting $y=\dfrac1x$, I get $$f(1)=e\left(\frac{f(x)}{e^x}+\frac{f(\frac1x)}{e^{\frac1x}}\right)\\\implies \frac{f(x)}{e^x}=-\frac{f(\frac1x)}{e^{\frac1x}}$$

Taking derivative on both sides, I get$$\frac{e^xf'(x)-f(x)e^x}{e^{2x}}=-\frac{e^{\frac1x}f'(\frac1x)\frac{-1}{x^2}-f(\frac1x)e^{\frac1x}\frac{-1}{x^2}}{e^{\frac2x}}\\\implies\frac{f'(x)-f(x)}{e^x}=\frac{f'(\frac1x)-f(\frac1x)}{x^2e^{\frac1x}}$$

Putting $x=1$ is not giving anything.

Comment: Let $g(t)=\exp(-t)f(t)$ and note the functional equation for $g$.

Comment: Rearrange once more, $\frac{f(xy)}{e^{xy}}  = \frac{f(x)}{e^x} + \frac{f(y)}{e^y}$, now can you see what is going on (with the substitution above?)

Comment: @Teresa_Lisbon yes, I can see clearly now that $g(x)=\ln x$, where $g(x)=\text{exp}(-x) f(x)$. Thus, $f(x)=\text{exp}(x) \ln x$. Thank you.

Comment: @user10354138 thankyou.

Comment: @saad I had searched this question on google as well as on this site. I didn't find any results. How are you able to locate such questions? I am asking this so as to avoid duplicacy in future.

Comment: [Approach 0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(xy)%20%3D%20e%5E%7Bxy%20%E2%80%93%20x%20%E2%80%93%20y%7D%20(e%5Ey%20f(x)%20%2B%20e%5Ex%20f(y))%24&p=1) gives you the results.

Comment: @arctic_char thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, I use a non-rigorous method to solve the problem, then I will fill in the gaps. If $f$ is differentiable, then I can use $y=1+\varepsilon$ in the limit $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$ to find the differential equation
$$f^\prime(x)=f(x) + \frac{e^x}{x}$$
which (using $f(1)=0$) solves as
$$\boxed{f(x)=\log (x) e^x}$$

Now, using the insight, I define $u(x)\equiv f(x)e^x$ and easily see that $u(xy)=u(x)+u(y)$ hence the rigorous proof.